# Error in Install TensorFlow GPU on Windows 11

Tags: tensorflow

After creating & activated environment,  I have installed cudatoolkit, But tensorflow not installing & getting Error:

1. conda activate deep
2. conda install -c conda-forge cudatoolkit cudnn
3. python -m pip install tensorflow

in above step , getting error

ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow

I have tried by giving versions too.

Comment: What is your python version?

Comment: version is 3.11.5

Answer (score 0):

According to the [TensorFlow compatibility chart](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source_windows#gpu) for Windows you can install only version 2.10 and below, and version 2.10 requires python 3.10 or lower.
So you can either lower your python version for your conda environment, or use [Windows WLS2](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip#windows-wsl2) to install TensorFlow >2.10.

This explains why you get the `(from versions: none)` error. For your python version (or system configuration) there is no tensorflow version available.